# the action 'navigate' with payload {"MainTabs"} was not handled by any navigator

Tags: react-native

I encountered the following error while developing react-native. I've read a few posts related to this error but the navigation structure was slightly different from mine. I also know that this is a problem that occurs when navigating between screen. But the example codes I read were clearly cases of having different navigation parents. But I am writing navigation as follows:

```
const RootStacks = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      {isInitializing? (
         <Stack.Screen name='LoadingScreen' component={LoadingScreen} />
      ) : isLoggedIn ? (
        <Stack.Screen name='AuthScreen' component={AuthScreen} />
      ) : isFirstSignup ? (
          <Stack.Screen name='AgreementScreen' component={AgreementScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen ...
      ) : 
          <Stack.Screen name='MainTabs' component={MainTabs} />
          <Stack.Screen ...
      )}
    </Stack.Navigator>
}

const MainTabs = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
      tabBar={(props) => <MainBottomTabBar {...props} />}
    >
      <Tab.Screen name='GroupScreen' component={GroupScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name='MatchTabs' component={MatchTabs} />
      <Tab.Screen name='ChatScreen' component={ChatScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name='MyScreen' component={MyScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  )
}
```

I want to navigate from 'AgreementScreen' to 'MainTabs'. But when running `'navigation.navigate ('MainTabs');` on the AgreementScreen, an error similar to the title of this article occurs.

*the action 'navigate' with payload {"MainTabs"} was not handled by any navigator*

I found out that I had to specify a parameter called `screen` during the investigation. Then the code should be modified as follows.

`navigation.navigate("SomeParentStack", { screen: 'MainTabs' })`

But I think AgreementScreen, MainTabs has the same parent navigator. And I don't know what value to put in instead of SomeParentStack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot navigate to the `MainTabs` Screen because they are not mounted at the same time. Either update your routing structure so that `AgreementScreen` and `MainTabs` are available at the same time, or you can navigate to `MainTabs` by updating the conditional rendering value for `isFirstSignUp` to `false`.

You can read more about navigation structuring here:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/